# Jquery tooltip to stay always open

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Is it possible to make the built in jquery tooltip to stay open after i access the page for the whole time i am on the current page?

I don't want to use any external libraries.

EDIT:I want to achieve something like an infobubble that will stay open above a button for extra information.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more about the functionality that you are trying to acheive?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent the tooltip from closing, you can stop the `mouseleave` event from bubbling (causing the tooltip to close).

```
$("a").on('mouseleave', function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).tooltip();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRwf7/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/nLBHd/1/

```
$(".navTabs").on({
mouseenter : function() {
   var topMeasure=$(this).offset().top +  $(this).height() + 2;
    var leftMeasure=$(this).offset().left;

    $(".arrow-up").css({
         top: topMeasure,
         left : leftMeasure+10,
        "visibility":"visible"
         })
         .show();

    $("#toolbarPopUp")
     .html($(this).attr('id'))
     .css({
     top: topMeasure + 5,
     left: leftMeasure,
     "visibility":"visible"
     })
     .show();
},
mouseleave : function() {
    $("#toolbarPopUp").hide();
    $(".arrow-up").hide();
}
```

});

```
<div id="tabRight">
<ul>
    <li class="navTabs" id="newsFeedTab">ToolBar</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div id="toolbarPopUp"></div>
```

check out the live Example in jsfiddle link... its pure jquery no extra plugin